# python layer with Caffe stucks after creating the layer

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I use the linreg.prototxt which uses `EuclideanLossLayer` provided in examples/pycaffe folder with the following command:

```
caffe train --solver solver.prototxt
```

solver.prototxt looks like:

```
train_net: "linreg.prototxt"
  base_lr: 0.001
  lr_policy: "step"
  gamma: 0.1
  stepsize: 50000
  display: 20
  momentum: 0.9
  weight_decay: 0.0005
  snapshot: 0
  snapshot_prefix: "linreg"
  iter_size: 2
```

Following output is generated

```
I0319 10:22:13.395200  9167 net.cpp:86] Creating Layer ipy
I0319 10:22:13.395220  9167 net.cpp:408] ipy <- y
I0319 10:22:13.395238  9167 net.cpp:382] ipy -> ipy
I0319 10:22:13.395268  9167 net.cpp:124] Setting up ipy
I0319 10:22:13.395287  9167 net.cpp:131] Top shape: 10 10 (100)
I0319 10:22:13.395314  9167 net.cpp:139] Memory required for data: 1280
I0319 10:22:13.395342  9167 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer loss
```

However the code does not progress after this and gets stuck.

What could be the possible reason? Thanks.